# Performance of Eclipse GEF/Draw2D for graphs with many nodes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, draw2d, eclipse-gef

How does drawing large (10.000 nodes) graphs perform when using Eclipse GEF or Draw2D? The nodes can be drawn very simplistic (a circle); no labels and stuff.

Is using GEF/Draw2D feasible for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it is very easy to test.

Take a look at [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/), which is a graphing toolkit based on draw2d. There are some useful [snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/snippets.php) provided. You can take one of those snippets, multiply the number of nodes drawn to 10K and see how it performs. From my experience with Zest, you should be up and running very quickly.

Comment: I've build a random binary tree with 10k nodes using Zest. It was sluggish but it worked and the nodes had a gradient as color. So I think some 10k nodes are possible with reasonable implementation.

Comment: @MacGyver I'm sorry. I was not able to find that old code anymore. The tool that requires this is not maintained (nor used) by me. But I know they are now using `jung` through a swing panel in Eclipse RCP.

Comment: Thanks ziggy!  Removed comment for confidentiality.